# Firebase 3 + Angular 2: SignInWithEmailAndPassword return undefined provider

Tags: authentication, firebase, promise, angularfire

Since few days when I authenticate with email and password, I got an error with my auth rules because the signin function is not returning anymore the provider.

In my console I can see "AUTH OK undefined VGeUoHi51CT7NjhLCi32yt7Gh5l2"

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($localstorage.get('email'), $localstorage.get('password')).then(function (result) {
            console.log("AUTH OK " + result.provider + " " + result.uid);
        }, function (error) {
            UtilityService.showToast("The app can't authenticate you, please re-login.", 'long', 'center');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The field now is called providerId as it is defined here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#email

Answer (score -1):

So in my rules, I can now put auth.providerid == 'password' ?

It's quite confusing as in the doc, there's still auth.provider mentioned..

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-integrate-auth

Comment: in your code depending the language you get the providerId... but in the security rules it is still called provider

Comment: also if you want to identify the provider in your code, you should also check providerData (mainly if you are using google,fb, etc), is an array with the info of the providers linked to an account,